# How should I store secret/credentials in my frontend app?

Tags: frontend

I want to embed some secret values in my frontend (React) app.
The secret is **not** something like password or API key but more general one e.g. Datadog token, Sentry token, etc.
In my understanding, in frontend app, the values are visible to uses through their browser, so they do not really need to be strictly secured. In the sense, is it an general way to store them in the source code directly and commit it to GitHub (private repo)?

Or, is there any other best practices?